# Have a single implementation for an MVC controller and Api controller

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an API controller and MVC controller that are identical in all ways except for the fact that one class implements ApiController and the other Controller.

They have same attributes, same actions, same responses. Is there a way to reduce code duplication here. Even if I move the implementation of the actions to a shared file, that still leaves the actions, attributes etc. to be duplicates.